# What's the Hamiltonian of a spin subsystem?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian

Suppose I have 10 spins that are interacting through the Ising model with a random potential: $\mathcal{H} = \sum J S_i^x S_{i+1}^x + \sum S_i^z$ for a system size of L = n spins. Now I want to take a particular subsystem (say the even or odd spins only) and calculate the Hamiltonian of the subsystem.

Firstly, am I conceptually correct in thinking that the Hamiltonian should be different for the subsystem (before I set out to calculate it)? Could you explain intuitively why it would be the same if it is?

Next, if it is indeed a different Hamiltonian, then how do I go about calculating it?

Assume here that we know of the density matrix of the system and the reduced density matrix of the subsystem.

Comment: Are you sure that the system is even separable into subsystems? Or are you making some sort of mean-field approximation?

Comment: As a general case, no it's not strictly separable. But I want to focus on the dynamics of the spins in this general subsystem. In the same way as we can define a reduced density matrix for a subsystem by tracing out the rest of the spins, can we do a similar thing for Hamiltonians? Or I'd my question nonsensical?